# redirect java.util.logging to log4j birt

Tags: spring-mvc, log4j, birt

I have a spring mvc webapp which uses BIT reports. BIRT reports uses java.util.logging. I am looking for a way to redirect the java.util.logging to log4.

The instructions at this link detail how to do it but I'm having some troubles getting the solution to work.

http://wiki.eclipse.org/BIRT/FAQ/Deployment#Q%3a_Can_I_use_Log4j_with_BIRT.3F

I've added the class as described. Then I added logging.properties into my webapp /resources directory with the following contents.

handlers=com.myer.reporting.logging.Log4jHandler

I don't think the system parameter applies since I am using a webapp?

Anyway I know it is not working because in my application logging directory I get the standard birt logs every time the application server re-starts.

[image]

Can someone help me with clarifying these instructions.

thanks

Answer (score 2):

I don't believe those instructions are acceptable for web application. Where there is a single JUL for the whole web server / servlet container.

If you generate report using BIRT API, BIRT allows you to set your own logger. See the method EngineConfig.setLogger(). It works at least in BIRT 4.3.1. We do as follows (it redirects BIRT logs to SLF4J, but the idea should be the same for Log4J):

```
EngineConfig config = new EngineConfig();
// set logger that forwards log messages to SLF4J

// as of BIRT 4.3.1 the custom logger will be accepted only if it or one of its parent in the BIRT's root logger list.
// see http://git.eclipse.org/c/birt/org.eclipse.birt.git/commit/engine/org.eclipse.birt.report.engine/src/org/eclipse/birt/report/engine/api/impl/EngineLogger.java?h=Kepler&id=1cb9507c8ce997bf5407a73d9c23487cef002fa9
java.util.logging.Logger julLogger = java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger("org.eclipse.birt" + ".myapp.Slf4jBridge");
julLogger.setUseParentHandlers(false);
Handler logHandler = new Slf4jLogHandler();
logHandler.setLevel(Level.FINEST);
julLogger.addHandler(logHandler);
config.setLogger(julLogger);
```

And the Slf4jLogHandler is implemented as follows:

```
public class Slf4jLogHandler extends Handler {
private Formatter julFormatter = new SimpleJulFormatter();

@Override
public void publish(LogRecord record) {
if (record == null) {
  return;
}
ClassLoader hanlderClassLoader = this.getClass().getClassLoader();
ClassLoader contextClassLoader = Thread.currentThread().getContextClassLoader();
if (hanlderClassLoader != contextClassLoader) {
  // do not log in foreign contexts
  /*
   * This check is necessary if several web applications with "JUL to SLF4J" bridge are deployed in the same Servlet container.
   * Each application has its own instance of SLF4J logger, but they all are mapped to the same JUL logger,
   * because the JUL logger is loaded by the root classloader. Whereas SLF4J loggers are loaded by their respective 
   * webapp classloaders. Thus comparing classloaders is the only known way to find out whom the JUL log record belongs to.
   */
  return;
}
String loggerName = record.getLoggerName();
if (loggerName == null) {
  loggerName = "unknown";
}
Logger slf4jLogger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(loggerName);
/*
* JUL levels in descending order are:
* <ul>
* <li>SEVERE (highest value)
* <li>WARNING
* <li>INFO
* <li>CONFIG
* <li>FINE
* <li>FINER
* <li>FINEST  (lowest value)
* </ul>
*/
if (record.getLevel().intValue() <= Level.FINEST.intValue()) {
  if (slf4jLogger.isTraceEnabled()) {
  slf4jLogger.trace(julFormatter.format(record), record.getThrown());
  }
} else if (record.getLevel().intValue() <= Level.FINE.intValue()) {
  if (slf4jLogger.isDebugEnabled()) {
  slf4jLogger.debug(julFormatter.format(record), record.getThrown());
  }
} else if (record.getLevel().intValue() <= Level.INFO.intValue()) {
  if (slf4jLogger.isInfoEnabled()) {
  slf4jLogger.info(julFormatter.format(record), record.getThrown());
  }
} else if (record.getLevel().intValue() <= Level.WARNING.intValue()) {
  if (slf4jLogger.isWarnEnabled()) {
  slf4jLogger.warn(julFormatter.format(record), record.getThrown());
  }
} else if (record.getLevel().intValue() <= Level.SEVERE.intValue()) {
  if (slf4jLogger.isErrorEnabled()) {
  slf4jLogger.error(julFormatter.format(record), record.getThrown());
  }
} else if (record.getLevel().intValue() == Level.OFF.intValue()) {
  // logger is switched off
} else {
  slf4jLogger.warn("Unexpected log level {}.", record.getLevel().intValue());
  if (slf4jLogger.isErrorEnabled()) {
  slf4jLogger.error(julFormatter.format(record), record.getThrown());
  }
}
}

@Override
public void flush() {
// noop
}

@Override
public void close() throws SecurityException {
// noop
}
}
```

This approach works even if there are several web apps using BIRT on the same server.

Comment: Any reason you wrote your own `Slf4jLogHandler` instead of using the SLF4J `org.slf4j.bridge.SLF4JBridgeHandler` one? Was it to do with logging in foreign contexts as per the code comments, or something else?

Answer (score 0):

I use a ServletContextListener, that install SLF4JBridgeHandler as unique handler for j.u.l. logger:

```
public class InstallJULHandlerListener implements ServletContextListener {
    @Override
    public void contextInitialized(ServletContextEvent arg0) {
        // Optionally remove existing handlers attached to j.u.l root logger
        SLF4JBridgeHandler.removeHandlersForRootLogger(); // (since SLF4J 1.6.5)

        // add SLF4JBridgeHandler to j.u.l's root logger, should be done once
        // during the initialization phase of your application
        SLF4JBridgeHandler.install();
    }

    @Override
    public void contextDestroyed(ServletContextEvent arg0) {

    }
}
```